# How can I get my building owner to deal with a mold issue?

Tags: bathroom, mold, ventilation, fans, ductless

I live in an apartment with no ventilation to the outside. The bathroom fan is ductless as is the range fan in my Kitchen. I have a mold issue in the apartment due to the lack of proper ventilation and because the age of the building they are not required to fix the issues. I have black mold behind my toilet and mold spots on my ceilings and mold on the windows in my bedroom. I have contacted the city and they have done nothing to help. There are people in this building with the same issue. What can I do to have the situation remedied.

Comment: They may not be required to fix the deficiencies causing the humidity and mold, but in many areas black mold may make the building uninhabitable until remedied.  You should include information about where you live, and you may also want to ask on one of the legal advice subreddits on Reddit, as it sounds like your question doesn't have much/anything to do with how to build things, or even how to remedy your specific problems.  Your question may be off topic.  Bear in mind if you press the issue and the authorities get involved, you may not be able to continue living there.

Comment: So grandfather clauses may allow the building to exist in its current form because it was deemed up to code at the time of construction, but separate from that you need to research laws related to health and safety in rental occupancies.  Depending on where you live, there may be laws protecting you separate from the building code.

Comment: If you are concerned about the mold have it tested. There are thousands of different types and only a few hundred are toxic. If the mold turns out to be toxic that can shut the building down regardless if it is a grandfathered building or not.

Comment: I live in IL, but the apartment is HUD subsidized and the landlord seems to not want to fix anything that is expensive. I have lived here for 11 years and the carpets have not been changed, along with the humidity due to zero mechanical ventilation. There apparently is no code for carpeting but I feel like I don't have the ability to have a healthy apartment because they do absolutely nothing to fix the mold or other issues with the carpeting.

Comment: Have you tried a dehumidifier?

Answer (score 3):

I'll attempt an answer that is limited to things you can control.  Maybe you should deal with your landlord or HUD but while you figure that out ......

Small amounts of mold that develop in an always-humid bathroom should be controllable by increased regular cleaning.   Twice weekly scrub down the walls, ceilings and other surfaces with a household mold/mildew remover from the supermarket.

I've never heard of a ductless bathroom fan before, but apparently they use carbon filters to extract humidity.  I don't entirely understand that ... the water has to end up somewhere but anyway, change the filter!   I bet you, the previous tenants, and the owner have *never* done that?  **Edit:** After reading up a little more on ductless bathroom fans, I'll modify my suggestion: These supposedly remove "odors" in a *dry* half-bath.  They are useless in a humid bathroom and in fact, may be contributing to your mold problem.  I'm changing my advice: Do replace the filter but do not turn on the fan when the bathroom is humid.  Use it only when the bathroom is dry and you want to "eliminate odors".  If you can't or won't replace the filter, *stop using this entirely*.  It is probably loaded with mold.

Get small cheap window fans for two windows in two different rooms, set up one blowing in and one blowing out.   That will create air flow through the apartment.  Do this especially during and after showering and cooking.

Get a window A/C, that will dry up the apartment ... if you are in a usually cold climate, get a dehumidifier.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[ Tilex, Broan Charcoal Filter, Window Fan, Dehumidifier ]

Answer (score 1):

Every public agency (like HUD) that subsidizes housing requires the housing owner to maintain and repair the rental unit.

Sounds like your landlord isn't doing their part. Contact HUD or your local public housing authority (which probably manages your rental) and complain.

Keep in mind, however, that if your landlord is violating the terms of his subsidized rental agreement by renting an unapproved space to you (and it's hard to imagine that a wholly unventilated apartment would be approved for rental) your complaint could result (as the comments note) in being forced to move out.

Comment: I would agree that this is definitely a time to get HUD involved. Maybe even get a group of tenants to write & sign a letter. Possibly contact a local lawyer who would be willing to do _pro bono_ work.

Answer (score 1):

Not all mold is bad. I’d have it tested by an independent testing agency (you may need to ask your doctor where it can be tested) and then give the report to your local Building Department if the owner does not fix it.

Let the owner know that you’re going to notify the Building Official (in writing) that the building is “unsafe” under Section 115 of the ICC code, unless he fixes the ventilation. If the owner does nothing, then notify your Building Department.  There may be a fee to have him inspect the facility and you may have to move.